# Can an inside of a variable be a name of another variable

Tags: c++

So if a variable type Char have something inside of it, can the inside be used to name a new variable for example an int in C++?

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code that shows what you are trying to do? Your description is not clear enough.

Comment: You better look at std::map class.

Answer (score 1):

No. Value of a variable cannot influence the name of a variable in C++.

What you may be looking for is a data structure such as an associative map. The C++ standard library provides a few of those.